# How can I write a $y$ with an upside down crescent/breve [solved] and what could that mean [unsolved]?

Tags: characters

I have stumbled upon [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc4bU.png) character. How can I write it and would could it mean? It was used in order to describe forecasts. There, it said:

> The forecast value for period $T + k$ (with $T = \text{end of the observation period}$ and $k = \text{number of observation points in the future}$) by point estimation is given by:
>   $$\hat Y = a + b * t$$
>   $$\hat y_{T + k} = a + b * (T + k)$$

$\hat y$ represents the very character.

**Edit:** I have found the [solution how to make such a character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38897/inverted-breve-accent-in-math-mode). But I still do not know what it could mean.

Comment: Looking at the formula, $Y$ and $y$ denote the same quantity, namely "The forecast value for period T+k by point estimation"

Comment: So, it might be a typo?